# Why do I always get error 500 filepond in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, filepond

I watched a tutorial on youtube about filepond (https://youtu.be/akaELMY2ORw) (source code from the video https://github.com/faris17/laravelfilepond) and I downloaded the source code.

In the video the code was working, but when I upload the image (instead of submitting the form) in my local, it is always returning a 500 error. I didn't change anything. Even though I followed another tutorial I got this error.

The header looks like this:

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Laravel's response looks like this:

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

##### View

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Latihan FilePond</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond@^4/dist/filepond.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <h2>Upload Image</h2>
        <form id="addForm" method="post" action="{{route('submitImage')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <input type="file" name="image" id='image' class='p-5'>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <button type="submit" id='saveBtn' class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond@^4/dist/filepond.js"></script>

    <script>
        //configuration filepond
        const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[id="image"]');

        // Create a FilePond instance
        const pond = FilePond.create(inputElement);

        //tujuan filepond
        FilePond.setOptions({
            server: {
                process: '{{ route('upload') }}', //upload
                revert: '{{ route('hapus') }}', //cancel
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                }
            }
        });
        //end config filepond

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#addForm").on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#saveBtn").html('Processing...').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                var link = $("#addForm").attr('action');
                $.ajax({
                    url: link,
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    type: "POST",
                    data: new FormData(this),
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function(response) {
                        $("#saveBtn").html('Save').removeAttr('disabled');
                        pond.removeFiles(); //clear
                        alert('Berhasil')
                    },
                    error: function(response) {
                        $("#saveBtn").html('Save').removeAttr('disabled');
                        alert(response.error);
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

##### Route

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::controller(ImageController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::get('/image', 'index');
    Route::post('/submit', 'store')->name('submitImage');
});

//route filepond
Route::controller(UploadController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::post('/upload', 'store')->name('upload');
    Route::delete('/hapus', 'destroy')->name('hapus');
});
```

##### Controller

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\TemporaryImage;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class UploadController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //process upload from filepond
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $filename = hexdec(uniqid()) . '.' . $file->extension();
        $folder = uniqid() . '-' . now()->timestamp;

        Session::put('folder', $folder); //save session  folder
        Session::put('filename', $filename); //save session filename

        $file->storeAs('files/tmp/' . $folder, $filename);

        TemporaryImage::create([
            'folder' => $folder,
            'image' => $filename
        ]);

        return 'success';
    }

    public function destroy(TemporaryImage $temporaryImage)
    {
        $temporaryFolder = Session::get('folder');
        $namefile = Session::get('filename');

        $path = storage_path() . '/app/files/tmp/' . $temporaryFolder . '/' . $namefile;

        if (File::exists($path)) {
            File::delete($path);
            rmdir(storage_path('app/files/tmp/' . $temporaryFolder));

            //delete record in table temporaryImage
            TemporaryImage::where([
                'folder' =>  $temporaryFolder,
                'image' => $namefile
            ])->delete();

            return 'success';
        } else {
            return 'not found';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the minimum code required to reproduce the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: hmm, is this `FilePond` an open source? at least you got to check whether it needs `/upload` (the `process` url) as `GET` route in the documentation. blindly following tutorial on the internet (which might be out of date) might be unwise. the [docs](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/server/#process) did say it only need `POST` but we can't be so sure about your version of `FilePond`.

Comment: try set the `fetch` property for `FilePond` as `null` and see if it changes things.

Comment: _"but when I upload the image (instead of submitting the form)"_ - difference being what exactly, considering that you currently appear to "do" your form submission _via_ AJAX?

Comment: `Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload` - so that appears to come from `process: '{{ route('upload') }}', //upload` specified in the filepond options. Your AJAX request however targets the form action URL, and that is `action="{{route('submitImage')}}"` - so it looks like this error does not come from your AJAX request, but either from submitting your form the "normal" way; or perhaps because filepond, based on that configuration, already handles the upload part itself ...?

Comment: @CBroe, "but when I upload the image (instead of submitting the form)". so when I upload the image, filepond will save it to local storage. and when I submit the form the image will be sent to the database.

Comment: @CBroe, ya, maybe the error does not come from AJAX request. maybe from filepond. Filepond should save image but in fact it doesn't do.

Comment: @BagusTesa I tried to set the fetch property but it not changes anythings

Comment: According to https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/server/#process, your `process` endpoint is supposed to return a unique "location id" for the file as `text/plain`, but I can't see your UploadController's `store` method doing that to begin with ...?

Comment: @CBroe I have do that but it still error. do you think should I change some config of php or apache ?

Comment: Can't make much sense of `Request Method: POST`, and then laravel saying the GET method was not supported. Are you sure you are looking at the relevant request there? Do you see any other requests in your browser dev tools, that might be connected to this? (Perhaps a POST followed by a GET, because the client received a redirect response.)

Comment: @CBroe, the problem came from connection of db. i check in browser dev tools then click network tab and i check preview section for upload network. 
it return "Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: insert into `temporary_images` (`folder`, `image`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (64b546682d144-1689601640, 1771675729435661.jpg, 2023-07-17 13:47:20, 2023-07-17 13:47:20)) in file D:\Document\Programming\laravelfilepond-main\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 742
"